# Can I make Mongo map reduce count multiple values of an object?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I have a collection that I am trying to map reduce by id and date to produce a graph for sales of a product in store vs online. A new object is created for each transaction, so I would like to reduce them to a total count for a given day. An object looks something like this:

```
object
{
      "ProductID": 1
      "Purchase Method": In Store
      "Date": 2018-01-16
      "Count": 5
}
```

What I am trying to achieve as output is to have in store and online purchases combined into 1 object with a key being the id and the date and then the value being the counts of each method as shown below:

```
ProductID: 1
Date: 2018-01-16
[
    {Name: "In store", Count: 3}
    {Name: "Online", Count: 2}
]
```

My current method was to map the objects by Id, date, and Purchase Method so the reduce would get the total count for that id on that date using that method, but this leads to having two entries for an id and date, 1 for in store and 1 for online. This is the current state of my functions:

```
var mapDailySales = function() {
var sale = this;

/*Converts timestamp to just date */
var pad = function pad(n, width, z) {
z = z || '0';
n = n + '';
return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join(z) + n;
};

var d = sale.Date;
var date = d.getFullYear() + "-" + pad(d.getMonth() + 1, 2, 0) + "-" + pad(d.getDate(), 2, 0);

emit({ProductId: sale.ProductID, Date:date, Method: sale.PurchaseMethod},
{Name: sale.PurchaseMethod, Count: 1})
};


var reduceDailySales = function(key, value) {
var res = {Name: 0, Count: 0};

value.forEach(function(value){
res.Name = value.Name;
res.Count += value.Count;
});

return res; 
};
```

Current Output looks something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "ProductId" : 1,
        "Date" : "2018-01-16",
        "Method" : "Online"
    },
    "value" : {
        "Name" : "Online",
        "Count" : 3
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve my desired output without map reducing again on the current output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation pipeline to get the results instead of mapReduce, `$group` by ProductID and Date, with `$project` you can map counts to an array

added `$out` to write the results to new collection, removing it will return a cursor

```
db.prod.aggregate([
    {$group : {
        _id : {ProductID : "$ProductID", Date : "$Date"},
        onlineCount : {$sum : {$cond : [{$eq : ["$PurchaseMethod", "Online"]}, "$Count" , 0]}},
        storeCount : {$sum : {$cond : [{$eq : ["$PurchaseMethod", "In Store"]}, "$Count" , 0]}}
        }
    },
    {$project : {
        _id : 0,
        ProductID : "$_id.ProductID",
        Date : "$_id.Date",
        counts : [{Name: "In Store", Count: "$storeCount"},{Name : "Online", Count: "$onlineCount"}]
    }},
    {$out : "count_stats"}
]).pretty()
```

collection

```
> db.prod.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a98ce4a62f54862fc7cd1f5"), "ProductID" : 1, "PurchaseMethod" : "In Store", "Date" : "2018-01-16", "Count" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a98ce4a62f54862fc7cd1f6"), "ProductID" : 1, "PurchaseMethod" : "Online", "Date" : "2018-01-16", "Count" : 2 }
>
```

result

```
> db.count_stats.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a98d3366a5f43b12a39b4ac"), "ProductID" : 1, "Date" : "2018-01-16", "counts" : [ { "Name" : "In Store", "Count" : 5 }, { "Name" : "Online", "Count" : 2 } ] }
>
```

if you want to use `mapReduce`, you can use finalize to reduce or transform the result further

```
db.prod.mapReduce(
    <map>,
    <reduce>,
    {
        out: <collection>,
        finalize: <function>
    }
)
```